# Django python dynamically generate field names while iterating over query set

Tags: python, django

I want to dynamically generate the field names inside a iteration over a queryset.

```
obj = tblFoo.objects.all()

    for obj in queryset
        for item in array
            print obj.item
```

The array has the filed names for the tblFoo

using obj.item gives an error the key doesn't exists, and using a string like,

'obj.' + item gives me the required string but it doesn't get the expected value.

Can anyone tell me how is this suppose to be done?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Is there a problem you are trying to solve? If you need to only return certain fields from a model, use [`only`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#only)

Comment: Use different names for 'obj': one for the queryset, one for the single item!

Comment: @Burhan Khalid I am using 'only', but the fields provided in 'only' (from array) are the fields I need to access in the iterator and the number of fields will always vary.

Answer (score 3):

Use `getattr(obj,'attribute_name_in_string')`

> getattr(object, name[, default])
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a
>   string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes,
>   the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x,
>   'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. If the named attribute does not
>   exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is
>   raised.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `getattr(obj, item)` to get the desired value. [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) is the python docs on the `getattr` function.

From the docs:

> For example, getattr(x, 'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar